# move_uploaded_file - Replace Name & Keep Extensionn

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a simple upload script in PHP which allows the user to add a photo but even though the image does upload to the relevant directory and does show up on the web page, it's not visible in my C: drive folder, so I'm wondering if I'm uploading it properly.  My code is:

```
$path = "../images/";
$extension = "jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $id . "." . $extension);
```

As I know that all images uploaded are `jpg` I'm pretty sure that this use of `$extension` is correct, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of writing this code, maybe using the actual file extension and just replacing the name.

Comment: Are you searching `C:` location? I believe you should be looking in your site's root folder. Assuming `id=3`, the image path will be '../images/3.jpg'.
Remember that `..` means changing directory to the parent of current directory. So you have to look in the parent directory of the file you are working in, find a folder called images and check if it's not available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following, this will help you keep the name as well as extension

```
$path = "../images/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path .$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

and if you want to change the name then

```
$path = "../images/";
$filename = "file_1";
$ext = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
$extension = ".".$ext[1];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path .$filename.$extension);
```

Comment: I believe that the extension will not work correctly since exploding a string does not include the separator but in concatenating `$path.$filename.$extension`, what you will get will be something like `../images/file_1jpg` assuming $extension is `jpg`. Please update your answer to include the period `.`.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this works but it's not adding a `.` between the file & extension

Comment: Be careful using this. Depending on how many people have permissions to upload, this is getting dangerous because as soon as someone uploads image.js.jpg the file will be saved as image.js !

Comment: Thanks @Marc, At the moment it's only me using the upload but I will keep this in mind if I allow others to use it in the future